# How to return a different type in a subclass method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this situation:

```
abstract class HasMethod<T =any> {
  abstract implementMe():T
}

class SuperClass extends HasMethod {

  implementMe() {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {

  implementMe() {
    return {            // <--- here is problem
      north: 'star'
    }
  }
}
```

it won't compile it says:

```
ts-test.ts:18:3 - error TS2416: Property 'implementMe' in type 'SubClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'SuperClass'.
  Type '() => { north: string; }' is not assignable to type '() => { foo: string; }'.
    Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ north: string; }' but required in type '{ foo: string; }'.

18   implementMe() {
     ~~~~~~~~~~~

  ts-test.ts:11:7
    11       foo: 'bar'
             ~~~~~~~~~~
    'foo' is declared here.
```

is there a way to return a different type from a subclass method?
In my case, "implementMe" is "getGraphData()" - I want to serialize each entity differently.

Comment: Make SuperClass return a more general type: https://tsplay.dev/N9nv1m (I used any, but it could be something else)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you cannot do what you are trying. You're changing the return type in the overridden subclass method. You might be able to get away with adding another field to the return object, instead of changing it. IE:

```
implementMe() {
    return {
        foo: 'undefined',
        north: 'star'
    }
}
```

The alternative is not to define fields in the superclass return obj, so it returns a type of `any`?

So in the superclass, you could have:

```
implementMe() {
    return {};
}
```

Either way, when you are overriding and returning the object, you're not changing its definition, you're building on what already exists by adding a field/property instead of changing the type.

In my second example, whilst you're effectively doing the same thing in adding a field to the return object, there is an additional risk of allowing the subclasses to override and then return anything at all, like a boolean or a string, which may cause unexpected issues later on?

EDIT: Based on the comments below, I notice its typescript and that the interface defines the return value with a generic type, but this is missing in the superclass, so you could try adding a generic for the return value

Comment: you could pass a different Generic type as T perhaps?

Comment: Its TS! Okay, that works then, something like:

    implementMe(): <T =any> {
        return { north: 'star' }
    }

perhaps?